# ? Your boss tells you not to bother taking off your coat

Tags: sentence-meaning

I read about this sentence "Your boss tells you not to bother taking off your coat" in a joke book. But I cannot catch the ethos of this kind of humor. Could someone please unravel it?

The original paragraph:

You can tell it's going to be a bad day when: Your boss tells you not to bother taking off your coat.

Comment: Is there any more to the joke?

Comment: Oh, I try to add it to see whether it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that when you show up to work, your boss tells you not to bother taking off your coat because you won't be staying - you're fired!

Comment: It's similar to a related joke about "Your coat is hanging on a shaky nail" or, in Scotland, "Yer jaiket's oan a shoogly nail".